# Python Json Parse "must be integers"

Tags: python, json, string

im trying to parse a json and it give error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afip.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(int(item['usuario']['denominacio
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My code:

```
import urllib.request
import json
url = 'https://url.com/file.json'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)

##parsing response
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
cont = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))
counter = 0

##parcing json
for item in cont['usuario']:
    print(item['usuario']['denominacion'])
```

my json:

`{"result":"success","usuario":{"nro_evento":2960505,"nro_secuencia_contacto":1,"Tipo_contacto":{"Cod_contacto":1,"Descripcion":null,"Visible":null,"Representante":0},"cuil":0000000000,"tipo_doc":0,"Tipo_doc_desc":null,"nro_doc":"0000000000","denominacion":"CAMARGO MAURO NAHUEL","telefono":0,"celular":0,"proveedor_celular":0,"mail":"","cod_area_tel":"","cod_area_cel":"","HabilitadoImpuestos":true}}`

Comment: The error you show does not match the code you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to loop?
Just this will do the work. Python made everything easy

```
print(cont['usuario']['denominacion'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in cont['usuario']:
```

item is the keys in `cont['usuario']`.(And all of them are strings in your json).

So if you want to get the `"denominacion"`:
You could just use:

```
print(cont['usuario']["denominacion"])
```

Comment: @KatiaSisHost, if this fixed your problem, click the checkbox on the left side of the answer to mark your question solved.